# Django-viewflow initial request data

Tags: django-viewflow

I am trying to implement a request fulfillment workflow, eg. service desk request, so the workflow starts with initial request data. I followed the quick start guide but it starts with `CreateProcessView` which is "internal" bound, what if the request comes from external website?

```
start = (
        flow.Start(
            CreateProcessView,
            fields=["text"]
        ).Permission(
            auto_create=True
        ).Next(this.approve)
    )
```

I presume it should be via the viewflow rest API? However there is no documentation about it since it's PRO version only. Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

To Start a flow with an initial data instead of user input, you could use flow.StartFucntion - http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.StartFunction